# How to send values from Pywebview javascript to Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm working from this code here, and when I click the html button I get an error stating 'nonetype'

```
    <button onclick="sendValue()">Send Value</button>
 function sendValue() {
            // Get the input element by ID
            var element = document.getElementById('inputValue');
            var value = element.value;
            // Call the PyWebview function to send the value to Python
            window.pywebview.api.send_value(value);
        }

class InputValueReceiver:
    def sendValue(value):
        # Call a Python function to handle the input value
        handle_input_value(value)
api = InputValueReceiver()
window = webview.create_window("PyWebview Input Value Example", html=html_content, js_api=api)


def handle_input_value(value):
    print(f"Received input value: {value}")

webview.start(debug=True)
```

I've tried both the official exapmle here: https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview

and this example: https://github.com/samfisherirl/PyWebview-Simple-Examples-Update-DOM-Elements-without-Javascript-knowledge

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:

```
window.addEventListner("pywebviewready",function (){
    sendValue()
});


function sendValue () {

    // Get the input element by ID

    var element = document.getElementById('inputValue');

    var value = element.value;

    pywebview.api.send_value(value)
}
```